# How can i convert CSV in JSON like I want

Tags: python, json, csv

Hello I show you my problem's :

I right that for convert my csv in Json. But the résult is not exactly what I Want .

**main.py**

```
import csv
 
filename ="forcebrute.csv"
 
# opening the file using "with"
# statement
with open(filename, 'r') as data:
  for line in csv.DictReader(data):
      print(line)
```

**csv**

```
name;price;profit

Action-1;20;5

Action-2;30;10

Action-3;50;15

Action-4;70;20

Action-5;60;17
```

**result i have**:

```
{'name;price;profit': 'Action-1;20;5'}

{'name;price;profit': 'Action-2;30;10'}

{'name;price;profit': 'Action-3;50;15'}

{'name;price;profit': 'Action-4;70;20'}

{'name;price;profit': 'Action-5;60;17'}
```

**And I would like this result:**

[image]

Comment: Show textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Scuse me , i'am french , can you explain me what is the properly formatted ? Is not correct my question ?

Comment: The link to the image should be replaced by text formatted as code (with the `{}` button). Everything else is formatted properly.

Comment: I just have this picture , you want i copy and write the picture image ?

Comment: Ok, in this case it can remain a picture. I have edited it to be visible in the question at least.

Comment: The CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ can convert csv to JSON exactly like this https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint With the plug-in installed you can do `Plugins > CSV Lint > Convert data > Convert to: JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the column delimiter then you can use *json.dumps()* to give you the required output format

```
import csv
import json

with open('forcebrute.csv') as data:
    print(json.dumps([d for d in csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=';')], indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Action-1",
    "price": "20",
    "profit": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action-2",
    "price": "30",
    "profit": "10"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action-3",
    "price": "50",
    "profit": "15"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action-4",
    "price": "70",
    "profit": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action-5",
    "price": "60",
    "profit": "17"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly what i want . Can you explain me how it fort , i watch there is a loop for , and convert to dict ?

Comment: @MY.D The DictReader class is iterable so we can utilise that to build a list (list comprehension). json.dumps() handles the formatting

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be using pandas, also quite fast with large csv files. It might need some tweaking but you get the point.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';')
data = json.dumps(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Comment: That is my first step at the begening , but doesn't work , the result is the same ...

Comment: Qour question contains nothing about using pandas. It helps if your question is clear and complete about what you tried and how.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Dictreader` from the `csv` library to read the contents of the CSV file and then convert the contents to a list before using `json.dumps` to turn the data into JSON.

```
import csv
import json

filename ="forcebrute.csv"

# Open the CSV file and read the contents into a list of dictionaries
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
   csv_data = list(reader)

# Convert the data to a JSON string and print it to the console
json_data = json.dumps(csv_data)
print(json_data)
```